# Capistrano not deleting old releases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm aware of the `keep_releases` option in capistrano and I have this set in our deploy script.  The problem I'm having is I think more related to permission issues.  I tried running `cap deploy:cleanup` but I get a permission denied error when trying to delete directories inside `tmp/cache`.  I'm using fragment caching which is why I have lots of files inside `tmp/cache`.

Can someone shed any light how to fix this issue?  I have to manually delete the folders in the server in order to clean up the releases folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I just have to pass use_sudo

```
cap production deploy:cleanup -s use_sudo=true
```

Answer (score 0):

i will try to change the owner of your directory to the user you use for capistrano:

```
sudo chown -R capistrano_user /path/to/www/app
```