# Unable to delete old releases using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, rbenv

I recently upgraded my Rails application from Ruby 2.7.3 to 3.0.1. Now I'm unable to delete old releases when deploying with Capistrano. I get the error below

```
 DEBUG [f5dff474]       rm: cannot remove '/home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20210527195617/tmp/cache/bootsnap/compile-cache/36/9709c0fbdbcd6c': Permission denied
```

I tried `chmod -R 777` and `chown $USER` on `shared/tmp/cache/`

I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15263784/504963),  I get the error

```
OptionParser::AmbiguousOption: ambiguous option: -s


Caused by:
OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: s


Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

I've also tried setting `set :use_sudo, true`

#### config/deploy.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
# lock '3.13.0'


set :application,     'my-app'
set :user,            'deploy'

set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :appsignal_config, name: 'MyApp'
set :appsignal_env, :production
set :appsignal_revision, `git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1`

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             false # https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq#known-issues-with-capistrano-3
set :use_sudo,        true
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :keep_assets, 5

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
set :keep_releases, 5

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '3.0.1'
set :migration_role, :app
# set :bundle_binstubs, -> { shared_path.join('bin') }
# set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}
set :linked_files, ['.env.production']
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system db/backups/production}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

task :restart_sidekiq do
  on roles(:worker) do
    execute :service, "sidekiq restart"
  end
end
after "deploy:published", "restart_sidekiq"

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Make sure local git is in sync with remote.'
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts 'WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master'
        puts 'Run `git push` to sync changes.'
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Run rake yarn:install'
  task :yarn_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install")
      end
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
  before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get this resolved by running `sudo chown deploy app/myapp/releases`. Still pops up from time to time, but this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Feels like your capistrano might not be the same as the one in the referenced answer.
You can perhaps skip the -s param and just try:

```
cap production deploy:cleanup use_sudo=true
```

Notice that since 3.x some parameters like use_sudo are not necessary anymore.

You can also try to prefix the cleanup cap with sudo and see what happens:

```
sudo cap production deploy:cleanup
```

It is quite possible that neither will work and then I would suggest to check this doc: [upgrading capistrano from 2.xx](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/f5a16779a7e6ddf6768ea2c1f39b101ffeba796b/docs/documentation/upgrading/index.markdown) More specifically the item 2 where it recommends to capify project from scratch and to move old cap files manually.

**EDIT**: Can you use sudo and manually remove the directory in question?

```
sudo rm -rf /apps/myapp/releases/20210527195617/tmp/cache/bootsnap/compile-cache/36/9709c0fbdbcd6c
```

If that works - that means you need to adjust permissions so that your capistrano user is allowed to remove the folder. If not able to do so, manually cleanup previous releases and from there on new deploys done with the new user should work.

Comment: Neither of these works. My capistrano version is `3.16.0`

Comment: Can you share what errors you are getting with the two commands suggested and whether you have tried to capify project from scratch...

Comment: It's the same error I posted above ` DEBUG [f5dff474]       rm: cannot remove '/home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20210527195617/tmp/cache/bootsnap/compile-cache/36/9709c0fbdbcd6c': Permission denied`. I have tried to cap from scratch, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You already found a solution that works for you, but other way to force deletions without setting first the correct owner / permissions is to remap the "rm" to "sudo rm":

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rm] = 'sudo rm'
```

so every "rm" call in capistrano will use "sudo rm" instead. Of course your capistrano user needs a passwordless sudo.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resort to using `sudo` to run commands, you could try checking what group your user belongs to by running `groups [your username]` on your server.

When you have that information, you could add it to your deploy.rb:
`set :group, "[your group]"`.

This fixed some permission denied issues I was having on project that no longer was deleting releases.